# Can I deploy multiple instances of my application on the same windows phone?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, deployment, windows-phone

I would like to deploy two or more instances of my application, however VS informs me that there is already an installed instance of this application on my phone.

[image: Message from Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition]

**How can I install/deploy multiple instances on the same phone for debugging?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, No. We cannot deploy multiple instances with same product id.

I am not sure why you want to do this but if you do want to deploy two or more instances (for you not for the device), generate a new GUID and replace product id in `Property/Assembly.cs`(assembly guid), `Property/WMAppManifest.xml` (product id) and `Package.appxmanifest` (product name).

See if it can meet your test requirement. But I will suggest you share what you want to test and see if others can share some tips.